# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with driver.current_url() (Python 3.6)(Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, scrape

My code:

https://pastebin.com/WKHZwAib

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver as web

url = 'https://www.wta.org/go-outside/hikes/hike_search? sort=&rating=0&mileage:float:list=0.0&mileage:float:list=25.0&title=&region=all&searchabletext=&filter=Search&subregion=all&b_start:int=0&show_incomplete=on&elevationgain:int:list=0&elevationgain:int:list=5000&highpoint='

driver = web.Chrome('D:/Development/Projects/Test/test/chromedriver')

driver.get(url)

driver.current_url()
```

I am getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable on driver.current_url(). Any tips on how I can resolve this?

I am going to be running through the pages on this site and grabbing each URL. If there is another way to do this that would avoid this, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use only `driver.current_url` instead of `driver.current_url()`.

From the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html):

> Some attributes are callable (or methods) and others are non-callable
>   (properties). All the callable attributes are ending with round
>   brackets.

So, `current_url` is a property and not a method hence you don't *call* it.

**Usage Example (Python 3) :**

```
my_url = driver.current_url
print(my_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I swore I tried this but I must have not.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `driver.current_url` without parenthesis.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url

The message error tells you that `driver.current_url` is a string, and as you can't call a string object, `driver.current_url()` can't be interpreted.

Comment: I swear I tried this but I must have not. Thanks for the answer!